# How to convert cURL to Axios request

Tags: node.js, curl, axios

I am trying to convert a cURL request from [here](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/nz-post-group/b8271f09-2ad8-4e1c-b6b1-322c5727d148/shippingoptions-api/api/2.0.0/pages/Authentication/) to Axios.

```bash
curl -d "grant_type=client_credentials\
&client_id={YOUR APPLICATION'S CLIENT_ID}\
&client_secret={YOUR APPLICATION'S CLIENT_SECRET}"\
https://oauth.nzpost.co.nz/as/token.oauth2
```

This works fine (when I put my credentials in).

I tried the following code:

```
import axios from "axios";

async function testApi() {
  try {
    const b = await axios.post("https://oauth.nzpost.co.nz/as/token.oauth2", {
      client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      grant_type: "client_credentials"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

testApi();
```

This fails with `Error 400. grant_type is required`. I have tried putting it as a parameter, enclosing within a `data: json` block. I can't figure this out.

Comment: Silly, but try putting `grant_type`, as first key?

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar - no , sorry. Doesn't work

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it , I needed to put the values in parameters

```
import axios from "axios";

async function testApi() {
  try {
    const b = await axios.post("https://oauth.nzpost.co.nz/as/token.oauth2",
        params: {
          client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          grant_type: "client_credentials"
        });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

testApi();
```

Comment: You have add null in between. 

async function testApi() {
  try {
    const b = await axios.post("https://oauth.nzpost.co.nz/as/token.oauth2", null, {
        params: {
          client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          grant_type: "client_credentials"
        }});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

Answer (score 5):

`curl -d` is a shorter way of saying `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d`. It is a **POST request** even though `-X POST` is not specified!

So make sure you configure your Axios request as a POST request, while also ensuring your **data is URL Encoded** with the `Content-Type` header set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. For example...

```js
const response = await axios({
  url: 'example.com',
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  // For Basic Authorization (curl -u), set via auth:
  auth: {
    username: 'myClientId',
    password: 'myClientSecret'
  },
  // This will urlencode the data correctly:
  data: new URLSearchParams({
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
  })
};
```

Comment: Encoding with `new URLSearchParams` was what I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Axios [already sets](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/649d739288c8e2c55829ac60e2345a0f3439c730/dist/axios.js#L1514) `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so that `headers:` part is unnecessary.

Answer (score -3):

Paste your command

```
curl -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=aaaaaaaa&client_secret=bbbbbbb" https://oauth.nzpost.co.nz/as/token.oauth2
```

into https://curlconverter.com/node-axios/ and it will convert it into

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const response = await axios.post(
    'https://oauth.nzpost.co.nz/as/token.oauth2',
    new URLSearchParams({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': 'aaaaaaaa',
        'client_secret': 'bbbbbbb'
    })
);
```

or many other libraries such as `fetch()`, Python's requests etc.