# how to transform a cURL to axios

Tags: curl, axios

I have this cURL which work fine,

```
$ curl -X POST --insecure --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Basic Y21lc3ZtOnZQfCsrNXBNQmxibTkl" -d "{
"filter": "",
"kind": "cluster",
"sort_order": "ASCENDING",
"offset": 0,
"length": 10,
"sort_attribute": ""
}" "my_url"
```

I would like to perform the same post request, i have a bad request error

note that i have to bypass the ssl certificate (done in curl with --insecure and in axios by rejectUnauthorized: false)
the problem is in the data
someone have an idea ?

i saw this post but it doesn't respond to my problem :
[How to convert cURL to axios request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370000/how-to-convert-curl-to-axios-request)

Comment: Can you post the code of the way you are doing it with axios??

Comment: no it give me bad request error, i tried the get and it work so defenetly it's about data

Comment: Can you show how are you sending the data using Axios?

Comment: this is what it look like my actual axios code :

axios({
        method:'POST',
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }),
        url,
        auth: {
            username: '*****',
            password: '*****'
        },
  headers:{
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   rejectUnauthorized: false,
   
  },
  data: {
     "kind": "cluster",
    
  }
 
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        res.send(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

Comment: I guess you are running into such situation because your axios request is not according to the documentation, I mean you are not sending the things right way. See Request Config in axios doc(https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: thank you for the reply, i saw their github doc and i didn't help 
i would like just to know the equivalent of -d in cURL in axios

Comment: it was body instead of data 
it's a shame that they don't mention it in their documentation and let us strugling to find out

Comment: data works absolutely fine for me.