# How to convert cURL to axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, axios, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to do this curl request into axios

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: image/png' --upload-file /tmp/exponent_avatar-1615597420129 'https://storage.googleapis.com/PATH/Screenshot_43.png?X-Goog-Algorithm=&X-Goog-Credential=ServiceAccount&X-Goog-Date=20210313T010340Z&X-Goog-Expires=901&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=content-&X-Goog-Signature='
```

with this axios config

```
      await axios
    .put(url, path, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": mimetype },
    })
    .then(async (data: any) => {
      const signedUrl = await generateV4ReadSignedUrl(
        fullRoute,
        "read",
        mimetype,
        "GET"
      );
      resolve(signedUrl);
    })
    .catch((err: any) => {
      reject(err);
    });
```

path variable is the route of the temporary file route, I don't find the way to do it on axios with

--upload-file /tmp/exponent_avatar-1615597420129

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370000/how-to-convert-curl-to-axios-request

Comment: it's not the same behavior.

Comment: I understand that then you need to attach a file? this question is with POST but it can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files.

I recommend changing the title of your question

Comment: Thanks guys, i just resolved it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert cURL to axios request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370000/how-to-convert-curl-to-axios-request)